# home assistant Mqtt switch strange after update

Tags: home-assistant, arduino-esp32

The switch have worked well until home assistant update!
but after I can't solve this problem.
I made my room light switch with esp32-dev Kit v1 like this
[just drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfQgt.png)

Arduino code here

```arduino
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

const char *ssid =  "olleh_WiFi_BA83";   
const char *password =  "0000002583"; 

const char* ID = "테스트";  // Name of our device, must be unique
const char* TOPIC = "room/light/ahn"; 
const char* INTOPIC = "room/light/Switch";
const char* mqttUser = "dragon";
const char* mqttPassword = "qazwsxedcrfvtgbyhnujm";
const char* broker = "172.30.1.48";

WiFiClient wclient;
PubSubClient client(wclient); 
char messages[50];
int state = 0;
int state1 = 0;
int state2 = 0;
int SW_state = 0;
int light = 4;

// Connect to WiFi network
void setup_wifi() {
  Serial.print("\nConnecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Received messages: ");
  Serial.print(INTOPIC);
  for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
    Serial.println((char) payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1') {
    state = HIGH;
    state1 = LOW;
    client.publish(TOPIC, "1");
  } else if((char)payload[0] == '0') {
    state = LOW;
    state1 = HIGH;
    client.publish(TOPIC, "0");
  }
  digitalWrite(4, state);
  Serial.print(state);
}


// Reconnect to client
void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(ID, mqttUser, mqttPassword)) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      Serial.print("Publishing to: ");
      Serial.println(TOPIC);
      Serial.println('\n');
      client.subscribe(INTOPIC);

    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println("\n try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  pinMode(light, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
  delay(100);
  setup_wifi(); // Connect to network
  client.setServer(broker, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()){
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();
  if (digitalRead(5) != SW_state) {
    state2 = state;
    state = state1;
    state1 = state2;
    digitalWrite(4, state);
    snprintf(messages, 75, "%ld", state);
    client.publish(TOPIC, messages);
  }
  SW_state = digitalRead(5);
}
```

and home assistant 'configuration.yaml' here

```html
#Switch
switch:
  - platform: mqtt
    name: "불"
    command_topic: "room/light/Switch"
    state_topic: "room/light/ahn"
    payload_on: "1"
    payload_off: "0"
    state_on: "1"
    state_off: "0"
    qos: 0
    retain: true
```

when I turned off home assistant( raspberry pi ) the switch works well
the problem is that when I turn the light 'on' using switch, esp32 send messages to home assistant.
the server got messages(on) perfectly and state changed but home assistant send messages to esp32 'off' messages then esp32 turn off the light right away
please help!
guys

Answer (score 0):

Sorry It was my fault maybe.........
YesterDay was rainy day so I wanted to know my house humidity and temperature so I connected DHT 11 sensor on my another ESP32 Board
and copied my switch code and edited code
but I didn't change esp32-ID  "테스트" above
few minutes ago I don't like name "테스트"
so I changed to "Fxxk" and uploaded
Then, Surprisingly It do its job well!!!
so far mqtt device name doesn't matter but I think it's important now.
thanks